# How do I expose Processing.js functions to the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, api, import, processing

I've got a redraw() function that is designed to halt the current draw() loop, retrieve new initialization values from the DOM, and resume drawing as if the values were those in the first place.

But "redraw()" in onchange can't see the Processing.js redraw() function, so changing the value in the input field has no effect. If "redraw()" is changed to "alert('changed!')", a popup displays "changed!", so we know the problem isn't the onchange, but an inability to import the redraw() function from the Processing.js file.

wolfram-automata.html

```
<p>Rule: <input onchange="redraw()" id="rule" value="110" size="4" /></p>
<canvas id="sketch" data-processing-sources="wolfram-automata.pjs"></canvas>
<script src="processing-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

wolfram-automata.pjs

```
processing.setup = function () {
    size(bounds, steps);
    background(white);

    rule = parseInt(document.getElementById("rule").value, 10);

    currentState = initState(bounds);
    rule = bits(rule);
}

processing.draw = function () {
    drawState(currentState, currentStep);
    currentState = step(currentState, rule);
    currentStep++;

    if (currentStep >= steps) { noLoop(); }
}

function redraw() {
    println("Redrawing");

    noLoop();

    currentState = [];
    currentStep;

    processing.setup();

    loop();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Processing.js function from HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414370/how-to-call-processing-js-function-from-html)

Comment: Voted self as duplicate too soon. The "dup" doesn't say how to expose code specified in <canvas data-processing-sources="code.pjs"></canvas>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a scoping issue. Try explicitly setting redraw on window.

Instead of:

```
function redraw() { ...
```

Try:

```
window.redraw = function() { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should include `processing-1.1.0.min.js` first, since `processing` is not defined inside `wolfram-automata.pjs` at that point.

```
<script src="processing-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="wolfram-automata.pjs"></canvas>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but it doesn't seem to help.